# does it take more energy to lower the temperature of something as you get closer to absolute 0?

Tags: low-temperature-physics

Instinctively I would assume it would take exponentially more energy to get from 0.01 to 0.001 (Kelvin) then it would to get from 2 to 1 (Kelvin). Otherwise it seems like it would be quite easy to get to absolute 0 which I know to be impossible.

At the same time I don't see why it would be more difficult since the former increment is a minuscule  fraction of the latter.

So if it is the case, then why is it so? And if it isn't then why is it such a great achievement when we get a fraction of a degree colder?

Comment: On what do you base this instinct?

Comment: Actually, the heat capacity of solids goes down very quickly at low temperatures, so the absolute amount of energy is very small in ultracold cryogenics experiments. Unfortunately, so is the efficiency of the refrigeration mechanisms, which makes it ever harder to reach ever lower temperatures.

Comment: @AcidJazz this is not relevant because, despite whatever the article implies, negative temperatures do not involve approaching or crossing 0K.

Comment: @Rococo point taken, I thought it might be of general  interest to the OP, but it may just be confusing, I'll delete it just in case. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the efficiency of an idealized refrigerator using a carnot process is (according to wikipedia, I have the correct derivation stowed away with my notes in the attic) The carnot cycle is the most efficient cycle for 2 heat reservoirs.
$$ \frac{Q_l}{W_h}=\frac{T_l}{T_h-T_l}$$ 
now as the surrounding area stays at more or less the same temperature, the amount of heat you can extract for a given amount of work will decline.

The problem isn't really that you need to extract more heat for the last few degrees (the inverse is true) it's that it's more difficult to do so.

Comment: I've read that in order to reach the bose Einstein condensate, they used magnetic fields and lasers, is there some analogous formula that could be used to show the decay in efficiency with respect to that as well?

Comment: I don't know how they used magnetic fields, probably to trap the particles?

Comment: As far as laser cooling goes, the particle needs to have a certain speed for an electron to jump to a higher energy level (and thus lose momentum). 
However, particles in a gas have a maxwell-boltzman distribution and there will be less and less particles with the required speed.

I suppose with an ideal, tunable, single wavelength laser one could counteract this effect, I don't know enough about it.

Answer (score 1):

It takes an infinite amount of energy to pump all heat energy from an object to a warm environment using a heat pump.

Let's say the cooling is done by a Maxwell's demon. To reach absolute zero, the demon must go trough the work cycle infinite number of times. As each cycle requires the same non-zero amount of energy, the total required energy is infinite.

A fundamentally different way of cooling:

In empty space make an arbitrary long cylinder with a piston, put some gas in the cylinder when the piston is down, let the gas do work by pushing the piston. This way of cooling the gas only takes a limited amount of energy, no matter how much you cool the gas. Note that all heat energy that disappeared was converted to mechanical energy. This device is not a heat pump, it's a heat engine.